# Wavy underline behaves strangely in chromium

Tags: css, chromium

I have an issue with `text-decoration-style: wavy` in Chromium (73).

when the text decoration switches between `solid` and `wavy`, sometimes it is like it only renders the upper part, leaving the lower part in its previous state. It doesn't happen all the time for some reason I don't understand.

Is there anything I can do about it ?

```css
div {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-style: solid;
}

div:hover {
  text-decoration-style: wavy;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello world</div>
```

Excepted rendering :

[image: excepted]
[image: excepted hover]

Glitch :

[image: unexcepted]
[image: unexcepted hover]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Add padding to the `div`.
> 2. Use `wavy` for the hover with `outline`(kinda cheat code)

My guess is due to the underline on the div is what it is causing the issue.

```css
div {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  display: inline-block;
}

div:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration-style: wavy;
  /* looks like this code is needed */
  outline: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div>Hello world</div>
```

Comment: Thank you ! That `outline: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);` seems a bit hacky but it works !
If there's anyone else interested, please note that only `padding-bottom` is required (not necessarily full `padding`). Also, there is no need to change the `font-size` and `display`.

Comment: hahaha I gave padding just make it looks good from all direction when added border nothing else and font size if just to make sure it highlights more, those are nothing to do with the fix mean other people will know that for sure.